# Is there a tool that can check for null reference exceptions?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Is there a tool available that can scan code and check for possible null reference exceptions, i.e. where there is no code to check for null before calling a method / accessing a property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ReSharper can do this.

Answer (score 5):

Resharper will offer suggestions for when you might have accessed a member on an object that could be null.

In 4.0, "code-contracts" support this at compile time - for example, it will stop you passing a possible-null into a method that states it doesn't want one.

Answer (score 1):

resharper is checking

Answer (score 1):

RedGate has a commercial tool called [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/index.htm) that can analyse your (compiled) code and show which exceptions can be thrown from an given function. You can also find all methods that throw a particular exception.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may be interested in the new contracts goodies in .NET 4.0?